# On property change event handler

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a VSCode [extension](https://github.com/attdona/riot-code) I'm looking for a way to react when the user modify an extension property defined in contributes.configuration section of package.json.

Does it exists an event like onPropertyChange or some other way to register an event handler?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After re-reading vscode documentation I found myself an answer:

`workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration` callback receive a [ConfigurationChangeEvent](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-nameconfigurationchangeeventaspan-classcodeitem-id1326configurationchangeeventspan) when a config property is modified.

with the method `affectsConfiguration` it is then possible to react at the specific property change, for example:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration(event => {
        let affected = event.affectsConfiguration("riot.compiler");
        if (affected) {
            // rebuild cpp project settings
            setup();
        }
    })

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer later. Have a nice day:)